# AWS Elastic Beanstalk (.ebextension) config - Support .config file in IntelliJ

Tags: amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, phpstorm

I've tried to look for IntelliJ/PhpStorm/WebStorm plugins to support *.config files. It looked like a mess.

[image: Messed *.config file]

I found [AWS Elastic Beanstalk Integration](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7274-aws-elastic-beanstalk-integration) but doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, after a few research, looks like a good [solution](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-registering-file-types.html).

```
> File -> Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S)

> Editor -> File Types
```

EbExtension Files follow yaml syntax/format

```
> Recognized File Types -> choose YAML

> Registered Patterns -> Click (+) plus icon on its right side

> add *.config

> click Ok -> Apply

> Wait to finish indexing
```

[image]